# NS Series Notebook Sony vaio - windows failed to start

Tags: windows-7, sony-vaio, boot

I have Sony Vaio VGN-NS240E.

> **Windows Boot Manager**
>   
>     Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.
>
> To fix the problem:
>
> 1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. (I don’t
>         have the disc in my current country.)
> 2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
> 3. Click “repair your computer.” (I did but it was just going back to windows 
>         error recovery page.)
>
> Info: Windows failed to load because the system registry file is missing or corrupt.

What should I do? Kindly help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a recovery partition you can just boot to that.

- Start up your computer
- Repeatedly hit the f10 (this is the sony hot key to access the recovery partition) key on startup until the recovery wizard starts.
- Then just follow the on-screen instructions